# How to create horizontal line before and after chapter heading but not in table of contents

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning

[image]

I want to create a horizontal line before and after chapter heading (as shown in Picture) Chapter number at the Right hand side and chapter title at the middle. SO far I have this piece of code:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries\huge}
  {\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
  {3ex}
  {\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
  [\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]
```

But the output is not what i want. Horizontal Lines are appearing on table of contents,figures and tables too(I have back-end content table) and also chapter title is right aligned

Line is appearing before and after the heading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand well your problem, you can use the `numberless` key to have a different format for unnumbered chapters:

```
\documentclass{book}%
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}%
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[pagestyles, clearempty]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\bfseries\huge}
{\filleft\Large\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}
{3ex}
{\titlerule\vspace{1.5ex}\filright}
[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\titleformat{name=\chapter, numberless}[block]
{\bfseries\huge}
{}
{0pt}
{\filright}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Estimation, Propagation and Validation of Measurement Uncertainty}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625083/adding-horizontal-line-before-and-after-chapter-heading-in-scrbook), which asks how to make this code work for the documentclass scrbook rather than book (as this one uses).

Also, that question shows a slightly improved version of this code here, and most notably it includes a bunch of screenshots. (Just FYI.)